# WifiManager.updateNetwork not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifimanager, wifi

I have been using `Wifimanager.updateNetwork(wifiConfiguration);` in my app and it has been working on Kitkat, JellyBean & ICS, but now in Marshmallow it keeps returning -1 even when the wifiConfiguration is not null and has a valid networkId. Does anyone know the possible reasons for this ? Has something changed in Marshmallow regarding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Android 6.0 Wi-Fi and Networking Changes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-network),

> Your apps can now change the state of WifiConfiguration objects only if you created these objects. You are not permitted to modify or delete WifiConfiguration objects created by the user or by other apps.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement the WiFi priority using the new API's ?

Comment: or how to disable a network so the system won't automatically reconnect to it? Basically you can only disconnect now, but that won't make the system NOT attempt to reconnect. So yeah, apps can pretty much not disconnect per say unless they shut off the network...

Answer (score 0):

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;       


if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
     //your code here
 }else {
    requestContactPermission();
} 



private void requestContactPermission() {

int hasContactPermission =ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);

if(hasContactPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}else {
    //Toast.makeText(AddContactsActivity.this, "Wifi Permission is already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[]        permissions, int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
        // Check if the only required permission has been granted
        if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i("Permission", "Wifi permission has now been granted. Showing result.");
            Toast.makeText(this," Wifi Permission is Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("Permission", "Wifi permission was NOT granted.");
            } 

         break;

    }
}
```